# Non-static method App\Http\Models\Role::id_role() should not be called statically in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel and trying to create custom middleware for login.I am trying to get Role using middleware.But I am facing some issue.

```
class CheckRole
{
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if(Role::id_role() == $request->input('id_role')){
              echo "Yes";
        }else {
          echo "NO";
        }
    }
}
class Role extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'roles';
  public $field;
  public function id_role()
  {
     return $data = $this->all();
  } 
}
```

Any help ?
Thank You In advance

Comment: the function is not static.

Comment: The problem is in this statment `Role::id_role()` id_role method is not static !

Comment: and why r u using all datas to compare with `$request->input('id_role')`

Comment: `$data = $this->all()` will return a collection so you have to loop over it or chage your logic to get just one role and get its id

Answer (score 0):

As stared by @TsaiKoga, your custom function is not static, so you can't call it statically.

An alternative way to call it is to use an object of model:

```php
if (app(Role::class)->id_role() == $request->input('id_role')){
...
```